# Missing System.ProcessTemplateType in API Response for Azure DevOps Server 2020 On-Premise Instances

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, tfs

I've been using the Azure DevOps API, specifically the 'Get Project Properties' endpoint as per the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/get%20project%20properties?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). I'm attempting to get the process ID of the project name following this [post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-get-process-id-with-project-name/1185415), which has been working fine for the most part.

However, I've recently encountered an issue with some on-premise instances of Azure DevOps Server 2020. When I call the API for these instances, the response doesn't contain the `System.ProcessTemplateType` property, which I need for my application to function correctly. The strange thing is that this only seems to be happening with these on-premise instances, not the cloud ones.

Here's the API call that I've attempted, starting from version 4 and going up to version 6:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/projects/{PROJECTID }/properties?api-version=6.0
```

Is there an updated API for on-premise instances, or am I missing something? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.